# EmberJS and third-party libraries

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to implement digest auth in Ember app. To complete this I took this library - https://github.com/inorganik/digest-auth-request. But I have no idea how to use it in an app. Now my auth service looks next:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
    path: "some-path",
    username: "",
    password: "",

    me(successHandler) {
        var meRequest = new digestAuthRequest('GET', this.path + "/me", this.username, this.password);
        meRequest.request(successHandler);
    },

    setCredentials(username, password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        console.log(this.username);
    }
});
```

And I got following errors:

```
services/auth.js: line 9, col 29, A constructor name should start with an uppercase letter.
services/auth.js: line 9, col 29, 'digestAuthRequest' is not defined.
```

My only attempt was adding digestAuthRequest.js to vendor folder, and adding

```
app.import('vendor/digestAuthRequest.js');
```

to ember-cli-build.js.

Looks like it's completely incorrect. So what I need to do to use such library in Ember app?

P.S. EmberJS version - 1.13.

Comment: `app.import` adds the script to the build pipeline, and that's about it. if they have an npm package browserify that, otherwise try making a wrapper module for `digestAuthRequest` and importing that.

Comment: Could you share with me how to make wrapper module around this lib? Is there some common technique?

Comment: as i understand this module is neither bower not npm. Have a look here http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html and also you can wrap it as a es6 module making `export default function digestAuthRequest(method, url, username, password) {//code omitted` and putting someplace in your app. Then importing it to another file like so: `import MyDigestAuth from '../auth/auth.js';` btw have a look at ember-observer.com it has a lot of different options for auth plugins